# php replace function for large data dump from pdf

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm looking to cipher through a large output of text and insert css styling to the text. The columns remain the same each time, however the initial start of what I am trying to gather varies numbering from 1-50 sometimes it's 1-13 sometimes it's all 1-50.

I have tried the replace method for each number but I am not able to replace each variable to make it easily interpreted for integration.

The code I have is:

```
$text = $page->getText();
$search = array('1.  ');
$replace = array('<br />1. ');
$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
echo $result;
```

The output before formatting is:

DESCRIPTION QUANTITY UNIT PRICE TAX RCV DEPREC. ACV 1. Remove 3 tab - 25 yr. - composition shingle roofing - 21.25 SQ 52.83 0.00 1,122.64 (0.00) 1,122.64 incl. felt 2. 3 tab - 25 yr. - composition shingle roofing - incl. felt 24.67 SQ 186.84 199.43 4,808.77 (0.00) 4,808.77 3. R&R Drip edge 196.95 LF 2.33 16.27 475.16 (0.00) 475.16 4. Asphalt starter - universal starter course 100.58 LF 1.31 3.67 135.43 (0.00) 135.43 5. Ice & water barrier 118.94 SF 1.15 4.34 141.12 (0.00) 141.12 6. R&R Roof vent - turtle type - Metal 5.00 EA 51.09 6.55 262.00 (0.00) 262.00 7. R&R Flashing - pipe jack 3.00 EA 38.63 2.95 118.84 (0.00) 118.84 8. R&R Rain cap - 6" 2.00 EA 36.80 3.40 77.00 (0.00) 77.00 9. R&R Ridge cap - composition shingles 77.58 LF 4.67 7.04 369.33 (0.00) 369.33 10. Digital satellite system - Detach & reset 1.00 EA 31.40 0.00 31.40 (0.00) 31.40 11. Digital satellite system - alignment and calibration 1.00 EA 94.19 0.00 94.19 (0.00) 94.19 only 12. R&R Flashing - pipe jack - split boot 1.00 EA 76.00 3.76 79.76 (0.00) 79.76 13. R&R Gutter / downspout - aluminum - up to 5" 152.58 LF 7.13 49.56 1,137.45 (0.00) 1,137.45

I'm looking for it to translate into a table as follow for each line (1-~50):

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>DESCRIPTION</th>
<th>QUANTITY</th>
<th>UNIT PRICE</th>
<th>TAX</th>
<th>RCV</th>
<th>DEPREC.</th>
<th>ACV</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1. Remove 3 tab - 25 yr. - composition shingle roofing - incl. felt</td>
<td>21.25 SQ </td>
<td>52.83</td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>1,122.64</td>
<td>(0.00)</td>
<td>1,122.64</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way that I can complete this using javascript or replace within a replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this data is a real-world sample, you should be able to spit on one or more digits followed by a period, surrounded by whitespace on both sides. That will at least give you your individual lines.

```php
<?php

$text = <<<TAG
DESCRIPTION QUANTITY UNIT PRICE TAX RCV DEPREC. ACV 1. Remove 3 tab - 25 yr. - composition shingle roofing - 21.25 SQ 52.83 0.00 1,122.64 (0.00) 1,122.64 incl. felt 2. 3 tab - 25 yr. - composition shingle roofing - incl. felt 24.67 SQ 186.84 199.43 4,808.77 (0.00) 4,808.77 3. R&R Drip edge 196.95 LF 2.33 16.27 475.16 (0.00) 475.16 4. Asphalt starter - universal starter course 100.58 LF 1.31 3.67 135.43 (0.00) 135.43 5. Ice & water barrier 118.94 SF 1.15 4.34 141.12 (0.00) 141.12 6. R&R Roof vent - turtle type - Metal 5.00 EA 51.09 6.55 262.00 (0.00) 262.00 7. R&R Flashing - pipe jack 3.00 EA 38.63 2.95 118.84 (0.00) 118.84 8. R&R Rain cap - 6" 2.00 EA 36.80 3.40 77.00 (0.00) 77.00 9. R&R Ridge cap - composition shingles 77.58 LF 4.67 7.04 369.33 (0.00) 369.33 10. Digital satellite system - Detach & reset 1.00 EA 31.40 0.00 31.40 (0.00) 31.40 11. Digital satellite system - alignment and calibration 1.00 EA 94.19 0.00 94.19 (0.00) 94.19 only 12. R&R Flashing - pipe jack - split boot 1.00 EA 76.00 3.76 79.76 (0.00) 79.76 13. R&R Gutter / downspout - aluminum - up to 5" 152.58 LF 7.13 49.56 1,137.45 (0.00) 1,137.45
TAG;

var_dump(explode(PHP_EOL, preg_replace('/\s+(\d+\.)\s+/', PHP_EOL . '$1 ', $text)));
```

This outputs:

```
array (
  0 => 'DESCRIPTION QUANTITY UNIT PRICE TAX RCV DEPREC. ACV',
  1 => '1. Remove 3 tab - 25 yr. - composition shingle roofing - 21.25 SQ 52.83 0.00 1,122.64 (0.00) 1,122.64 incl. felt',
  2 => '2. 3 tab - 25 yr. - composition shingle roofing - incl. felt 24.67 SQ 186.84 199.43 4,808.77 (0.00) 4,808.77',
  3 => '3. R&R Drip edge 196.95 LF 2.33 16.27 475.16 (0.00) 475.16',
  4 => '4. Asphalt starter - universal starter course 100.58 LF 1.31 3.67 135.43 (0.00) 135.43',
  5 => '5. Ice & water barrier 118.94 SF 1.15 4.34 141.12 (0.00) 141.12',
  6 => '6. R&R Roof vent - turtle type - Metal 5.00 EA 51.09 6.55 262.00 (0.00) 262.00',
  7 => '7. R&R Flashing - pipe jack 3.00 EA 38.63 2.95 118.84 (0.00) 118.84',
  8 => '8. R&R Rain cap - 6" 2.00 EA 36.80 3.40 77.00 (0.00) 77.00',
  9 => '9. R&R Ridge cap - composition shingles 77.58 LF 4.67 7.04 369.33 (0.00) 369.33',
  10 => '10. Digital satellite system - Detach & reset 1.00 EA 31.40 0.00 31.40 (0.00) 31.40',
  11 => '11. Digital satellite system - alignment and calibration 1.00 EA 94.19 0.00 94.19 (0.00) 94.19 only',
  12 => '12. R&R Flashing - pipe jack - split boot 1.00 EA 76.00 3.76 79.76 (0.00) 79.76',
  13 => '13. R&R Gutter / downspout - aluminum - up to 5" 152.58 LF 7.13 49.56 1,137.45 (0.00) 1,137.45',
)
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/n01E5

From there, you are going to need to perform some additional rules, and I think you might end up writing a parser unless your data **exactly** matches this **every** time.

You might want to look at [extracting text with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6884297/231316), or possibly trying to [extract it as tabular data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638732/231316). Unfortunately, both of those examples are in C#.